# [Java][Jboss]classToLaunch cannot be null

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm beginner (Java/JBOSS), and I'm trying to launch JBOSS on Java EE, but I got always same error when I launch the server from Eclipse :

**With JBOSS 7.1.1**

> An internal error occurred during: "Starting JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server".
>   classToLaunch cannot be null

**Or with JBOSS EAP 6.1.0**

> An internal error occurred during: "Starting JBoss EAP 6.0 Runtime Server".
>   classToLaunch cannot be null

When I configure Server runtime environment, I have choice with :

- [JBoss Community]*JBoss 7.0 Runtime* or *JBoss 7.1 Runtime*
- [JBoss Enterprise Middleware]*Jboss Enterprise Application Platform 6.x Runtime*

One thing import think : I can't have internet connection where i'm installing the server (but I can copy from my local machine)

Versions :

- Eclipse Java EE, Kepler Release 2 (Build id: 20140224-0627)
- jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
- jboss-eap-6.1

Comment: I solved my problem by using a jdk installed and not a jdk copied (copy/paste)

Answer (score 2):

> Go to Window-> Preferences-> Server-> Runtime Enviroments-> Click on
>   the Runtime Enviroment(Which server you want to start)-> Click Edit->
>   Check Home Directory server location(May be wrong, Change the
>   Location)-> Finish